# @font-face not working in IE Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

I'm having trouble with a client site. The site is hosted at http://allisonbraun.com/sexified-sisterhood/ and is also accessible by redirect from http://sexifiedsuccesscircle.com

The @font-face rules I'm using to integrate the Pepita Script Font don't seem to be taken by Internet Explorer 11 and I'm stumped. Am I doing something wrong in the code?

Previously I ran into the issue that the rules weren't working in firefox either when visited via the redirect because it didn't like the fact that the font was hosted under a differnt domain. I've managed to fix that by adding

```
# BEGIN REQUIRED FOR WEBFONTS

AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# END REQUIRED FOR WEBFONTS
```

to the htaccess. It now works in firefox, but in IE it still doesn't work, no matter which url I visit from?

Would be so grateful for any help! Maybe I'm just being dumb and integrating the code wrong, but it seems to work everywhere else.

Best, Ffion

Comment: You need to add your code where you are attempting to add the fonts in.

Comment: just ignore IE, we need to make it disapear, and it starts with us. I told my boss that if he want things to work on IE he'd better hire another person because i will not drag IE any further, no more... And im still here, working without IE on my mind. =)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are only using the .ttf file from your font. Try to convert your font with a font-face generator like [FONTSQUIRREL](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and import it in that format (Fontsquirrel generates the CSS for you, just modify the path and use it):

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'FONTNAME';
   src: url('path_to_font.eot');
   src: url('path_to_font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('path_to_font.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('path_to_font.woff') format('woff'),
        url('path_to_font.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('path_to_font.svg#fontname') format('svg');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```